# Updating the cart number in Shopify with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, shopify

Apologies if this is somewhere else but I can't find a better way of doing this.

I want to update the cart total number in realtime with AJAX anytime a product is added, removed, or quantity is changed.

I have it working but there has to be a better way. It feels wrong to poll constantly for changes and I certainly don't want to end up with a memory leak.

Right now I have the item count being fetched from JSON and then changing the number in the div by polling every second, giving the user the illusion that the number is being updated when they change something.

I've tried adding a listener to the add to cart button (works) as well as listening on the quantity selector (doesn't work).

I'm sure I'm just being a noob so any help is appreciated. Code below:

```
// Fetch the cart in JSON and change cart quantity on the fly after first product added to cart
  function doPoll(){
    setTimeout(function() {
      $.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart) {
        $('.cart-count').html(cart.item_count);
        doPoll();
    }, 1000);
  }
```

## Update

So the fix was actually very simple. The reason I couldn't attach a listener on a particular element within the cart was the cart wasn't loaded yet via ajax (duh!)

So all I did was remove the constant polling and instead ran my function anytime the ajax on the page was fully loaded:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    //Do stuff here
});
```

Comment: Check in your `scripts.js` file for three functions- cart/add, cart/update, cart//remove and share what you find.

Comment: sorry HymnZ can you clarify a bit?

Comment: In your Shopify theme's section there'll be a scrips.js.liquid file which is a theme default. In that you'll have a specific set of functions related to cart. If you can share them, it'll be easier to help.

Comment: Should've clarified - I'm using a customized theme based on Timber (https://github.com/Shopify/Timber). The AJAX functions related to the cart are here: https://github.com/Shopify/Timber/blob/master/assets/ajax-cart.js.liquid but what I'm referencing in my function is the call to /cart.js using the API - https://docs.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api#get-cart

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's even simpler. If an ajax driven cart adjustment happens Timber gives you an overridable hook. Just override ShopifyAPI.onCartUpdate

e.g.

```
ShopifyAPI.onCartUpdate = function(cart){
    //do something new with the cart contents
    $('.cart-count').html(cart.item_count);
};
```

Other than that your cart count is also available on page load via liquid so if you combine the two you're covered:

```
<div class="cart-count">{{ cart.item_count }}</div>
```

Comment: This is where I was at previously.. it was working from the base theme but then I added a second .cart-count div (in the cart flyout drawer) and then it all went downhill from there lol.

I'll see if I can work this in... or perhaps just go back to the core functionality and just move the div rather than duplicating it.

Comment: What about `('.cart-count').each(function(){$(this).html(cart.item_count); });`

Comment: Apologies about the delay on this.. I found out what the problem was - amended my q to contain the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not implemented any other way to add to cart, it's very simple.

If you look in the AJAX functions file you have mentioned, especially in functions at lines 101 and 113, you can see that those function are related to cart update. Add your code `$('.cart-count').html(cart.item_count);` before `callback(cart);` and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - I'm definitely not going to alter core files though. Function overrides are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

A more up to date solution without Jquery. You can use fetch and then use the data returned to populate the cart count.

```
      fetch('/cart.js')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then((responseText) => {
        data = JSON.parse(responseText);
        var counterEl = document.querySelectorAll('.js-cart-item-count');

        counterEl.forEach((element) => {
          element.innerHTML = data.item_count
        })
      })
```